# How to send a file inside AXIOS PUT HTTP Request NextJS Internal and External API Call

Tags: node.js, axios, next.js, stream, put

I'm trying to upload a file to an internal API EndPoint using axios PUT Request, and from that endpoint make a second call to an external API. I presume that I have to convert the Buffer into a ReadableStream
How can I create the stream from the buffer, and pass this stream to an external api call.

1. Load file from FrontEnd
2. Call to Internal API Process the file
3. From the backend api endpoint, call to External API with the stream

```
 async function loadFile(e) {
  
    const result = await callAPI(e.target.files[0]);
  
  }

 async function callAPI(file) {

  await axios
    .put("/api/resource", file)   //<< File is sent as data to the internal endpoint
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("Response >>>", res);
      return res;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error Put Call>>>", err);
      return err;
    });

}
```

/api/resource

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import nc from "next-connect";

export default nc<NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse>() 
  .put(async (req, res) => {
   
    const chunks = [];

    req.on("readable", () => {
      let chunk;
      while (null !== (chunk = req.read())) {   
        console.log("Req read >>>>", chunk);
        chunks.push(chunk);
        console.log("LENGHT ", chunks.length);
/*
AT THIS POINT CONSOLE.LOG 

Req Read >>>> <Buffer 65 ba 28 c8 ed 70 87 b7 bb e8 ab e6 1a 65 a9 de c7 ec 06 6d 75 6f 35 3f 70 97 22 6d bf b8 47 78 c9 86 84 d1 46 cb 0b 21 2c fc 4d 0f 87 9b 5a 1b 78 fe ... 24079 more bytes>
LENGHT  557

*/
      }
    });
  });
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
```

Call External API

```
  const result = await axios
      .put(
        "https://www.example.com/api/asset/upload/id",
        (req as any).file,
        config
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
      });
```